# Ruby text variable with \ inside

Tags: ruby

I need to create a db record with a column with this value

```
query = "booster pro 12\24 v"
```

but this is what stored into db column.

```
"booster pro 12\u0014 v"
```

if I try with single-quoted I get

```
'booster pro 12\24 v' -> "booster pro 12\\24 v"
```

but If I use this, I got the correct string printed.

```
puts 'booster 12\24 v' -> booster 12\24 v
```

Comment: _"If I use this, I got the correct string printed"_ – that's because you found the correct solution. Backslash is an escape character. In a double-quoted string, you have to escape a literal backslash with another backslash (or use single quotes). See the docs for [string literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings).

Comment: BTW, `"\24"` is interpreted as `"\024"`, i.e. the _octal_ number 024 which is 20 in decimal and 0x14 in hex. Therefore `"\24" == "\u0014"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I try with single-quoted I get
>
> ```
> 'booster pro 12\24 v' -> "booster pro 12\\24 v"
> ```

This is correct. You've already got the right answer.

A backslash is an escape character. When displaying escape characters in a double-quoted string, you must escape them with a backslash. That means a *literal* backslash is represented by *two* backslashes.

Two literal backslashes would be represented by *four* backslashes, in a double-quoted string.

Or for example, consider:

- How would you display a **newline** character? Answer: `"\n"`
- How would you display a **backslash character, followed by an "n"**? Answer: `"\\n"`

This behaviour is not specific to ruby.

Comment: Backslashes are the escape character in ANSI SQL as well but I wouldn't be 100% confident that it will work with every db imaginable.

Comment: I didn't say "this is specific to every imaginable database and language", I just said it's not specific to ruby ;) .... However, backslash as an escape character is *very common* behaviour.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So even if it's stored as "booster pro 12\\24 v" (with double backslash) into db it's fine.

Comment: You don't *store* a double-backslash. You *display* it as a double-backslash. Because otherwise, as shown above, it would be impossible to distinguish between e.g. a backslash followed by n vs a newline character.

Comment: A double-backslash would be displayed as four backslashes. Four backslashes would be displayed as 8 backslashes. 8 backslashes would be displayed as 16 backslashes...